# Rails decimal returned as string in API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a field called price in my db which is a decimal field and in my JSON API response it is returned as a String.

I wanted to apply some validations to the field that would allow max 2 digits after period and found out that if I use decimal field I can then apply the precision on DB level.

`t.decimal "price", precision: 10, scale: 2`

Then I want to calculate total price in a service object:

## services/statistics/monthly_rides_generator.rb

```
class CurrentMonthRidesGenerator
    def initialize(current_user)
      @current_user = current_user
    end

    def call
      user_current_month_rides_by_day.map do |date, rides_on_day|
        {
          day: formatted_date(date),
          total_distance: total_distance(rides_on_day),
          avg_ride: avg_ride(rides_on_day),
          avg_price: avg_price(rides_on_day),
          total_price: total_price(rides_on_day)
        }
      end
    end

    ...

    def total_price(rides)
      rides.map(&:price).sum
    end
  end
```

## app/api/statistics/stats_api.rb

```
get '/current_month' do
  Statistics::CurrentMonthRidesGenerator.new(current_user).call
end
```

but in API response this field is a String.

```
{
    "day": "November, 8th",
    "total_distance": "9km",
    "avg_ride": "9km",
    "avg_price": "100.0PLN",
    "total_price": "100.0"
}
```

I want this field to be returned as it was saved because I need a float/decimal number in the front end to then do other calculations.

Why is it returning a String when it is a decimal field? How can I fix it?

Comment: Should I use `Money` gem to convert it to Float?

Answer (score 5):

It's returning as a string because Decimal/BigDecimal in ruby is a very precise number. Javascript/JSON doesn't have a data type that is as precise as ruby's BigDecimal.

You can easily see this in your browser if you open up the console:
[image]

If you convert the value to a float in your serializer then it will be a float in the JSON object that is returned by your API, but you'll want to be careful of how your clients use this data. If they don't use a library that can handle precision then you're going to get rounding errors and often be off on your calculations by a penny.

I've been using the decimal.js library for things like this and it works out great. https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/

Comment: Thanx for the rationale. I have some precision validations in db that rounds the number to 2 places after period and my clients will only get numbers with max 2 digits after period so that's not a problem

Comment: I think we shouldn't be careful about how clients use the data. An API should be autonomous and independent of its clients. Instead, the client should be aware of the API JSON schemas. It's up to the API designer choosing between rendering it as string or decimal.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is to cast it to the desired type in a serializer:

```
# app/serializers/your_model_serializer.rb

class YourModelSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :day,
             :total_distance,
             :avg_ride,
             :avg_price,
             :total_price

  def total_price
    object.total_price.to_f
  end
end
```

Comment: What if this method is not defined on a Model? I have this method defined in a service object. Will that still work?

Comment: Sure, you could call the service object from the serializer instead of `object.total_price.to_f`. EDIT: That is assuming you are calling an action on the controller associated with the serializer (e.g. `YourModelController` and `YourModelSerializer`).

Comment: If you update the question with more details about where the `total_price` method is defined, what the controller looks like, etc. I can provide a more definitive answer.

Comment: Can I not simply call to_f on it?

Comment: Well I'm not sure how Rails behaves when you call a service object directly within a route like you are doing...my solution works when you are using a more traditional controller + serializer convention, where subclasses of `ActiveModel::Serializer` give you more control over how Rails *serializes* the response.

Comment: Thanx. It is still weird that when you want to add precision on database level, say to 2 places after period, this is still a BigDecimal considered by Rails a 'large' number that should be converted to a String. I think not all arguments were taken into consideration while making the decision to make it a String.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to solve this problem by changing the column type to `Float`, renaming it to `price_cents`, adding `money-rails` and monetizing the column. Then I just call `to_f` or round the value right before displaying it or sending it to front-end in API response.